# Creating a function with a for loop into lapply

Tags: r, list, lapply

I am trying to use a simple function to perform an operation on a column of each dataframe of a list.
Here is the data:

```
a<-LETTERS[1:6]
b<-1:6

df1<-as.data.frame(cbind(a,b))
df2<-as.data.frame(cbind(a,b))
df3<-as.data.frame(cbind(a,b))

df_list<-list(df1,df2,df3)
```

These are the names I want to use to rename the dataframes in the list:

```
df_names<-c("first","second","third")
```

By far, I have done this:

```
df2_list <- lapply(df_list, function(df_list) { 
  for(i in df_list[[i]]$b) { 
    df_double<-list((as.numeric(df_list[[i]]$b))*(2))
    names(df_double)<-df_names[i]
  } 
  df_list
} )
```

That gives me this error:

```
 Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

But if I try to run separately these two commands, for instance on the first dataframe of the list, they do what I want:

```
df_double<-list((as.numeric(df_list[[1]]$b))*(2))
names(df_double)<-df_names[1]
```

I know I am missing something but I cannot see what... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lapply` to multiply the `b` column with 2 and use `setNames` to assign names.

```
setNames(lapply(df_list, function(x) transform(x, b = b * 2)), df_names)

#$first
#  a  b
#1 A  2
#2 B  4
#3 C  6
#4 D  8
#5 E 10
#6 F 12

#$second
#  a  b
#1 A  2
#2 B  4
#3 C  6
#4 D  8
#5 E 10
#6 F 12

#$third
#  a  b
#1 A  2
#2 B  4
#3 C  6
#4 D  8
#5 E 10
#6 F 12
```

For clarity, you may also do this in separate steps.

```
names(df_list) <- df_names
lapply(df_list, function(x) transform(x, b = b * 2))
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak, but now the error message is `Error in b * 2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator` (which I do not understand, as b is a numeric vector). I tried with `df1<-as.data.frame(cbind(a,as.numeric(b)))` but without success.

Comment: Don't use `as.data.frame(cbind(...))` only `data.frame` is enough. `df1<- data.frame(a,b)`. Do the same for other dataframes as well.